# SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers Does Not Retrieve Local Server Instances

Tags: c#, networking, sql-server-2012

I am using windows-7 Sp-1 and Sql server 2012 on my local system.
And Windows Server 2008 R2 Sp-1 and Sql server 2012 on server system.
When I use

### Code

```
SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers();
```

At that time it shows only network instance.
It doesn't show any local instance.
When I use

### Code

```
SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true);
```

then it returns blank data table.
What to do in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with the same issue from time to time at different computers, and I haven't find any explanation. Looks like that the problem somehow related to firewall, UDP packets and SQL Server Browser service on local machine (AFAIK, `SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers` uses SQL Server Browser even for local instances, and SQL Server Browser, in turn, uses broadcast packets to discover SQL Server services.

The workaround I've implemented uses [`ManagedComputer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.wmi.managedcomputer.aspx) class from SMO:

```
    private const String defaultMsSqlInstanceName = "MSSQLSERVER";

    public String[] GetLocalSqlServerInstances()
    {
        return new ManagedComputer()
            .ServerInstances
            .Cast<ServerInstance>()
            .Select(instance => String.IsNullOrEmpty(instance.Name) || instance.Name == defaultMsSqlInstanceName ? 
                instance.Parent.Name : Path.Combine(instance.Parent.Name, instance.Name))
            .ToArray();
    }
```

Moreover, it works faster, than `SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true)`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: for ManagedComputer which dll reference is required.

Comment: Sorry this is not working.It returns an string array with 0 elements.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently. I could not find any of the installed local instances of SQL server, so I turned on the SQL Server Browser. That seemed to fix my problems. The code I used looks like this:

```
            ServiceController oController = new ServiceController("SQL Server Browser");
            if (oController.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) || oController.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Paused))
                oController.Start();
```

This code uses the System.ServiceProcess assembly.

Answer (score 0):

go to services from starts menu and set the Sql Server(MSSQLSERVER),Sql Server Agmnt(MSSQLSERVER) and Sql Server Browser in start mode and chose startup type atuomatic in all of them